# Visual studio 2017 texttransform.exe exception

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\TextTransform.exe" "C:\Project Code\City Lodge\City-Lodge\Server\Automation\Lodgix.Server.Domain.Automation......\Server\Automation\Lodgix.Server.MetaData\Templates\4 - Domain\DomainGenerator.tt"
error : An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.PrepareNewCompilation()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.Compile()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.Compile(String source, String inputFile, IEnumerable`1 references, Boolean debug, SupportedLanguage language, String compilerOptions)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

I am currently facing a problem with TextTransform.exe from Visual Studio 2017. TextTransform.exe seems to work when I use -h but when I pass a template the above error gets thrown.

I debugged the same template using Run custom tool in Visual Studio and it worked fine.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Was Fixed with the latest Visual studio 2017 Update